# MongoDB & Node.js - Difference between pushing whole model to ref array and pushing id

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I want to know what is the difference between pushing the model to an array like this:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
clients: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]});

var user = new User();
UserIWillPushInto.clients.push(user);
```

and this:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
clients: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]});

var user = new User();
UserIWillPushInto.clients.push(user._id);
```

I am asking because if I have a model with only a few properties i can push the whole model into the array, but if I have a model with a lot of properties i get weird results (weird meaning sometimes works, sometimes does not and I cannot reproduce it when I want).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) to model your relationships when embedded documents are mostly unique and [document reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) when they are too big or often the same.

Good reading: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: Thank you for these references. So as I understood, for smaller models (one-to-few) I can push the whole model. But for larger (one-to-many or squillions) i push an _id (document reference)?